# Changing the notation of clabel in contourplot, processed by KDE

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm very new to Python and especially Matplotlib but I would like to change the amount of significant digits in a contour plot or preferably change the notation to scientific. 
I found sth like this, refering to Matlab: http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/33019

Is there any chance to do this? Additionally, I would like to change the background of the axis. So only the areas of contour are colored in different shades of blue. Is this possible.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import scipy.stats as st
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

data = np.loadtxt(filename)
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
xmin, xmax = 265, 675
ymin, ymax = 45,450

# Set Parameters from Autotracking
a1 = 277
a2 = 664
b1 = 51
b2 = 437
a = (a2-a1)
b = (b2-b1)
xm = a1+(a/2)
ym = b1+(b/2)

# Peform the kernel density estimate
xx, yy = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:200j, ymin:ymax:200j]
positions = np.vstack([xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([x, y])
kernel = st.gaussian_kde(values)
f = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, xx.shape)

fig = pl.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
# Contourf plot
cfset = ax.contourf(xx, yy, f, cmap='Blues')
cset = ax.contour(xx, yy, f, colors='k')
# Label plot
ax.clabel(cset, inline=1, fontsize=10, format='%.4f')
ax.set_xlabel('Bewegung in $x$-Richtung [px]')
ax.set_ylabel('Bewegung in $y$-Richtung [px]')
# Plot ellipse as border of system
ellipse = Ellipse(xy=(xm, ym), width=a, height=b, 
                    edgecolor='black', fc='None', lw=1.5)
pl.gca().add_patch(ellipse)
pl.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
pl.show()
```

This is my output:
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbThP.png)

Comment: If I correctly understood your problem you should look [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_label_demo.html), there's an example that format the labels of the contour.

Comment: I've tried it this way, but it seems to change the graph in a complete way. I'll post the output in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to follow the instructions of the example, I came up with sth like this:
[Graph2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvLom.png)
But this is not really what I would like to get. I just want to change the notation of the contour lines, because the kernel destiny is so small (approximately 0,0000334 e.g.). So there would be two possible ways:
1) Changing it to scientific notation: 3,34 * 10^(-5) (preferred way)
2) Expanding the amount of significant digits to be displayed

My code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import scipy.stats as st
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

data = np.loadtxt(filename)
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
xmin, xmax = 265, 675
ymin, ymax = 45,450

# Set Parameters from Autotracking
a1 = 277
a2 = 664
b1 = 51
b2 = 437
a = (a2-a1)
b = (b2-b1)
xm = a1+(a/2)
ym = b1+(b/2)

# Peform the kernel density estimate
xx, yy = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:200j, ymin:ymax:200j]
positions = np.vstack([xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([x, y])
kernel = st.gaussian_kde(values)
f = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, xx.shape)

fig = pl.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
# Contourf plot
cfset = ax.contourf(xx, yy, f, cmap='Blues')
cset = ax.contour(xx, yy, f, colors='k', locator=pl.LogLocator())
# Label plot
fmt = ticker.LogFormatterMathtext()
fmt.create_dummy_axis()
ax.clabel(cset, inline=1, fontsize=10, fmt=fmt)
ax.set_xlabel('Bewegung in $x$-Richtung [px]')
ax.set_ylabel('Bewegung in $y$-Richtung [px]')
# Plot ellipse as border of system
ellipse = Ellipse(xy=(xm, ym), width=a, height=b, 
                    edgecolor='black', fc='None', lw=1.5)
pl.gca().add_patch(ellipse)
pl.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
pl.show()
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Two things: 1) You should update your question and not post an answer unless you have found something that solves all or part of your problem. 2) the important line of the example is this `plt.clabel(CS, CS.levels, inline=True, fmt=fmt, fontsize=10)`. You should use the `fmt`
 option.

Comment: What's strange is, when I add    fmt = ticker.LogFormatterMathtext() to clabel no numbers are displayed. Am I doing sth. wrong?

Comment: Actually what is happening is that the contours are outside the plotting window, I guess that the error is in the computation of xx, yy or f. (Try to change min, max to see more and you should also see the contours, at least is what I saw testing your code with random x, y). I will give it another try later on.

Comment: So I changed the values of min and max, but unfortunately it didn't help. hmm this is really strange though.

Comment: Change the value of min and max does not resolve the problem but should let you understand it. Did you saw the contours? I see all of them with the labels (in scientific log notation) outside the blue regions. The problem is in the computation off the contours values.

Comment: Although I changed the max and min in every direction, I saw the contours with lines, but couldn't find any value.

Comment: Other idea: isn't it possible to multiply the outcome of the kde with a value, like 1000 or sth like this? So you could easily tell clabel to take these modified values and add 10^(-3) as text after it.